# Express/AngularJs "angular is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am following the lessons on egghead.io trying to learn Angular. This lesson is about $http, and for some reason I can’t get a basic Expressjs/Angular app running.

Lesson link: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-http

Here is my directory stucture:

```
app.js
public/
    index.html
    main.js
package.json
node_modules/
bower_components/
```

Here are my files:

public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Egghead Videos</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

<input type="text" ng-model="app.person.firstName" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="app.person.lastName" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="app.addPerson(app.person)" />

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in app.people">
        {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());
app.set('port', 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

var data = [
  {"firstName": "Jeff", "lastname": "Winger"},
  {"firstName": "Troy", "lastname": "Barnes"},
  {"firstName": "Britta", "lastname": "Perry"},
  {"firstName": "Abed", "lastname": "Nadir"}
];

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.send(data);
});
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

public/main.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http) {
    var app = this;
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .success(function(data) {
        app.people = data;
      })

    app.addPerson = function(person) {
        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/users", person)
          .success(function(data) {
            app.people = data;
          })
    }
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "users-app",
  "description": "users test app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "latest",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "cors": "*"
  }
}
```

So I made some changes from last time based on the comments, but it is still not working.

To run it I am typing "node app.js" in the command line. Is that correct, or should I be typing node “public/main.js” to run the app? I am a little confused about that part.

When I type "node app.js" nothing happens and the browser says it can’t connect at localhost. When I type "node public/main.js" it says "angular not defined".

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure `"../vendor/angular.js"` exists. this could be the reason

Comment: you're missing `app.listen(3000);` in app.js. Then you can connect to localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Egghead.io code had quite a few omissions.
The http server was not listening on any port,
bodyparser.json middleware was required and issues on the client.

The following will work for you.

```
>npm install

>node server
```

browse to //localhost:3000

File Structure:

```
server.js (I prefer instead of app.js for Node/Express server code)
public/index.html
      /js/app.js

package.json
node_modules/
```

SERVER.JS

```
/* ========================================================== 
External Modules/Packages Required
============================================================ */
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

/* ========================================================== 
Create a new application with Express
============================================================ */
var app = express();

/* ========================================================== 
serve the static index.html from the public folder
============================================================ */
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

/* ========================================================== 
Use Middleware
============================================================ */
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
//  extended: true
//}));

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));

/* ========================================================== 
Port the server will listen on
============================================================ */
app.set('port', 3000);


var data = [
  {"firstName": "Jeff", "lastname": "Winger"},
  {"firstName": "Troy", "lastname": "Barnes"},
  {"firstName": "Britta", "lastname": "Perry"},
  {"firstName": "Abed", "lastname": "Nadir"}
];

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.send(data);
});

app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
});

/* ========================================================== 
Bind to a port and listen for connections on it 
============================================================ */
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
    console.log("========LISTENING On Port 3000=========")
});
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Egghead.io</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

  <input type="text" ng-model="app.person.firstName" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="app.person.lastName" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="app.addPerson(app.person)" />

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in app.people">
        {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}} 
    </li>
  </ul>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

APP.JS (save under /public/js)

```
/*================================================
Module
================================================*/
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

/*================================================
Controller
================================================*/
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http, $scope) {

    var app = this;

    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .success(function(data, status, headers) {
        console.log("http status code= "+status);
        console.log("data from server= "+JSON.stringify(data));
        app.people = data;
      })

    app.addPerson = function(person) {

        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/users", app.person)          
          .success(function(data, status, headers) {
            console.log("http status code= "+status);
            console.log("data from server= "+JSON.stringify(data));
            app.people.push(data);
            console.log("new app.people= "+ app.people);
          })

          .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error with post" + status);
          })
    }
});
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "Angular-HTTP-Example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "From Egghead Example",
  "main": "node server.js",
  "author": "Mick",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Mick that worked great! So I was missing Angular routing, and listening on a port.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your client-side files to a folder (`public` in this example) and add the middleware to serve static files, then correct your paths.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

Comment: Hey thanks Ben. I added that to my app.js file, but it is still not working. See my code edits above.

Answer (score 2):

You load Angular from `../vendor/angular.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/angular.js"></script>
```

but looking at your folder structure it should be in `bower_components`.

Anyway you can simply load Angular from a CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gpx, but it is still not working. I made some changes to the code above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are also getting a 404 error for the angular.js library or add a appropriate source for the library, using a CDN or using bower and setting it as public dir.

Comment: Hey Ashok, thanks for trying to help but it is still not working. See my code edits above.

Comment: If you are learning angular js only, you can put all your code inside a apache server or nginx server, and get rid of the hassle of setting up a node server just to serve static http files.